# Using Slugify in Django urls

Tags: python, django, slug

I'm trying to create SEO friendly urls where all spaces are replaced with a hyphen.

This is how I'm 'slugifying' the URL by using slugify in Django templates

```
<a href="{% url 'dj' dj_name=dj.name|slugify %}">
```

Here is my urls.py

```
url(r'^top100/(?P<dj_name>[a-zA-Z0-9 \'&-]+)/$', views.dj, name='dj')
```

This is my view

```
def dj(request, dj_name):
    dj = DJ.objects.get(name=dj_name)
    dj_song_list = Song.objects.filter(artist=dj, duplicate=False).order_by('-votes', '-release_date')
    return render(request, 'hunt/dj.html', {'dj_song_list': dj_song_list, 'dj':dj}
```

Now the `%20` in the urls has changed to a `-` but I get the error `DJ matching query does not exist.`

Also this ignores `&` in the DJ name. For example it changes the url for the DJ `Above & Beyond` to `www.example.com/top100/above-beyond`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to request an object **with its slug instead of its name in database**. The slug is a string, compute from the original name, which you can use in URL (because it's SEO-friendly). But you can't request objects with it if you don't have save this slug anywhere in your database. Indeed, it's impossible to retrieve the original name from the slug.

```
Above & Beyond --> above-beyond --> Above @ Beyond  }
                                --> above & beyond  } A lot of possibilities...
                                --> ABOVE - BEYOND  } 
                                --> ...
```

You need to use a [`SlugField()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) and get the object wanted according to this new field. Short example:

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField('slug', max_length=100, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField('news content')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('news-view', args=(self.slug, ))

# In the app/urls.py:
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>.+)/$', view.news_detail, name='news-view'),
    #...
]

# In the 'news_detail' view (app/views.py)
news = get_object_or_404(News, slug=slug)
```

In practice, you can use the templatetags `slugify` if you want to use clean URL like stackoverflow: they're using the ID of the question to retrieve the content from the URL, but there's also the title, which you can change, it'll redirect you anyway.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377984/using-slugify-in-django-urls
                                   ^^^^^^^^
                                   ID used  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                            slug just for SEO purpose, not
                                            used to retrieve from the db
```

Comment: @Maxime - Nice explanation I must say. I've a doubt. While getting news object from the model like `news = get_object_or_404(News, slug=slug)`, wont querying `slug` field takes a lot of time? I mean its not indexed and even if we index it, write queries will be heavy. Isnt it? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast If I remember correctly my DB postgraduate courses, indexing strings uses hashes in the B-tree index. So it adds a relatively small cost of computing the hash comparing to integers.

However, if you don't put index on the `slug` field, it is indeed way slower than querying the primary key, when your table gets (dozens of?) thousands of entries. But this is another problem, that you should know when your database starts to get bigger than a casual blog with less than 100 entries.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use [SlugField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) in your models ?
Then you can queryset on your slug. 
I guess the error comes from the queryset on name instead of a slug.