# How do I turn my urls into readable names?

Tags: python, django

I have been creating a Hackernews type clone recently and bumped into some trouble with adding a more readable url. I believe it's called a Slug from what I've read.

Basically, my urls read something like: localhost/1/, localhost/2/ which are taken from the Category model. Instead of reading /1/, /2/ etc, I would prefer it to take the category_name field and populate the url. For instance localhost/engineering, localhost/science.

Here is my category model:

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"
```

Here is my current url.py:

**url.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'stories.views.category'),
```

and my views.py:

**views.py**

```
def category(request, category_id=1):
    template = 'stories/category.html'
    category = Category.objects.get(id = category_id)
    return render_to_response(template, {
        'category': category
        })
```

How should I go about implementing something like this? I've read things about Slugify, but could never get it to work properly. Thankyou.

Comment: What's stopping you from changing `<category_id>` to `<category_name>` and then `category = Category.objects.get(category_name=name)`

Comment: I tried this! It didn't work unfortunately. Was there anything else I needed to change around to make it work?

Comment: @akalikin the "doubleplusungood" habits while reading a django tutorial :)

Comment: Well all the logic of retrieving category by id should be done with name instead, but otherwise I don't see why it wouldn't work. Of course it's another question if you have duplicate categories stored. Post your attempt and we'll be able to help you

Comment: Just got it to work! Cheers @akalikin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your urls.py should be,

```
url(r'^(?P<category_name>\w+)/$', 'stories.views.category'),
```

while, the views.py should be something like,

```
def category(request, category_name):
    template = 'stories/category.html'
    category = Category.objects.get(category_name = category_name)
    return render_to_response(template, {
        'category': category
        })
```

the above, might work if you are not using slugified category_name. If you do, then use a slug field in your model as mentioned by [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21378236/887007)